# VueJS Will empty data affect component performance?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

There's a Vue2 project and some of the components are written with empty `data` or empty hooks `updated`. Like this:

```
export default {
    // Other code is deleted for brevity 
    data: () => ({
    // This is empty
    }),
    updated() {
    // This is empty
    },
};
```

Will empty `data` or life cycle hooks affect the component performance in any way? How can it be tested?

Comment: Absolutely not. You can test it using the developer tools of your favourite browser. In general, when doing web dev, you don't really have to care about such performance issues; instead you should really be watching over things which take time, like the network or I/O.

Comment: @paul-stenne There are people, who suggested this is a bad practice. Although I can see the logic in removing unnecessary code, I'd expect this to have zero or little affect on performance. Hence, we should not really spend too much time on removing these empty properties. Just trying to find out if there's any implications that I'm missing.